# How to see all ROS topics and messages used by turtlebot3?

Tags: ros

I am looking for all topics and messages used by turtlebot3. I know I can find with rostopic and rosmsg commands but it is a bit wasteful. Is there any document or tool for this ? Like turtlebot3 uses 'x' topic with 'y' message to publish laser scan data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools available.
The first, that comes to my mind is `rosnode info`. You need to call it with the name of the node. Node names can be discovered with `rosnode list`. Those tools easily shows you services, subscriptions, and publications of a given node.

```
$ rosnode info /turtle_pointer
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/turtle_pointer]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /turtle2/cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist]

Subscriptions: 
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
 * /tf_static [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /turtle_pointer/get_loggers
 * /turtle_pointer/set_logger_level
 * /turtle_pointer/tf2_frames
```

Another good solution is `rqt_graph`. It will plot all nodes and messages as
graph.

Comment: Thank you. I know these commands but I am looking for different answer. For instance, /tf_static (in your example) used for what ? Actually, I am looking for detailed document which explain these. Do turtlebot3 provide any detailed document for this ? I could not find.